# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, upload, express

I am getting an error with an aspx Upload Control & Drop Down List on a single aspx page.

Here is the error...

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here is my code for the on_submit...

```
protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsValid)
        {
            string uploadDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/files/");
            //string uploadDirectory = "//DOCSD9F1/TECHDOCS/";

            string uploadFolder = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

            string fileName = e.UploadedFile.FileName;

            string path = (uploadDirectory + uploadFolder + fileName);

            e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(path);
            e.CallbackData = fileName;
        }
    }`
```

here is my code for creating the drop down list...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("D:/SMGUpload/SMGUpload/files");

            DropDownList1.DataSource = di.GetDirectories();

            DropDownList1.DataBind();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo i in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = i.FullName;
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = i.FullName;
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Are you able to step through in a debugger to see which specific object is null?

Comment: I suspect you're getting the exception when hitting the line DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text; Try a debugger and see what comes up there.

Comment: string uploadFolder = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

This is what is throwing the exception... it was not doing that until i started calling .SelectedItem but not sure how else to form the path

Comment: @bluetickk: Sounds like either `DropDownList1` or `.SelectedItem` is `null`.  Can you debug to find out why?

Comment: Dont you think you need to Re-bing your Dropdownlist on Every PostBack irrespective of isPostBack? When FileUploadComplete Event Occurs, your DropDownList1 has no Elements in it (not Databound)!!

Comment: Can you show the markup (ASPX)? Is ViewState enabled on the page and DropDownList?

Comment: ok so i removed the if(ispostback) so that it will rebind on ever page load... but i added that after it stopped working anyways

Comment: DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text is null... but i dont understand why?

Comment: Is SelectedItem also null or only SelectedItem.Text? Do you have ViewState disabled (in the markup)?

Comment: Just SelectedItem.Text is null , let me read up on ViewState before i make a fool of myself

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack){
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("D:/SMGUpload/SMGUpload/files");
    DirectoryInfo[] diArr = di.GetDirectories();
    DropDownList1.DataSource = diArr;
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Name";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

And get the selected value like:

```
string uploadFolder = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

FYI: Make sure there are proper slashes(/) in the path you are creating while uploading the file.