# DropDownList1.SelectedValue is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I cannot get anything other than a null value from my drop down box, im trying to upload files to different directories...

```
public class dropDownInfo
{
    public string pathName { get; set; }
    public string pathValue { get; set; }
}

string uploadFolder = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // reference to directory
        //DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("//DOCSD9F1/TECHDOCS/");
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("D:/SMGUpload/SMGUpload/files/");

        // create list of directories
        List<dropDownInfo> DropDownList = new List<dropDownInfo>();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo i in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            dropDownInfo ddInfo = new dropDownInfo();
            ddInfo.pathName = i.FullName;
            ddInfo.pathValue = i.FullName;
            DropDownList.Add(ddInfo);
        }
        DropDownList1.DataSource = DropDownList;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "pathName";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "pathValue";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uploadFolder = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
}

protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsValid)
    {
        string uploadDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/files/");
        //string uploadDirectory = @"\\DOCSD9F1\TECHDOCS\";

        string fileName = e.UploadedFile.FileName;

        //string uploadFolder = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

        //string path = (uploadDirectory + uploadFolder + "/" + fileName);
        string path = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(uploadDirectory, uploadFolder), fileName);

        e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(path);
        e.CallbackData = fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: and using dropdownlist1.selecteditem.value; gives me a reference exception.

Comment: @bluetickk can you try DropDownList1.SelectedValue?

Comment: Can you show the page mark up for DropDownList1?

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="280px"></asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Are you positive that "D:/SMGUpload/SMGUpload/files/" is correct?.  If it does exist, you  won't get anything back if it is empty.

Comment: 100%, no matter what directory i chose the drop down list always populates the fields, but in the code behind they are always null

Comment: Where in the code are you seeing the null? In the upload_complete or the index_change event?

Comment: both, they never change. even when I hardcode the items into the list, it seems like they never change index

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object reference not set to an instance of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269258/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

Do a check before you access the `Value` property.

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem != null)
    uploadFolder = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: doesnt explain why the items are null =/

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown has no values after postback. You are only binding at first page load, then the page posts back (index changed) and the items are not re-bound.

Comment: So.. what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have viewstate disabled on the page or any of the controls? This could cause the issue you are describing.

Also, the local variable uploadFolder will never be preserved between post backs. You need to store it in the session or on the page somewhere.

```
Session["uploadFolder"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value
```

Comment: now its just uploadfolder that is null.. i placed a label to confirm that the dropdownlist1.selecteditem.text was working and it is... but for some reason my uploadfolder refuses to take the value

Comment: The 'uploadFolder' variable will be reset each post back. Stick it in the session or use DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-set the DataSource on post back, but don't re-bind it or that will reset the selected index as well.